# Rust - How to expose struct out of module?

Tags: rust, module

This probably a very dumb question, but I was wondering if it was possible to expose a type out from a module. If this sounds vague, I hope the following info will shed light on what I want to achieve.

Let's say I have the following file structure:

```
Project
|-Units
| |-Length
| | |-Meter.rs
| | |-mod.rs
| |-mod.rs
|-main.rs
```

The Units/mod.rs file:

```
pub mod Length;
```

The Units/Length/mod.rs file:

```
pub mod Meter;
```

The Units/Length/Meter.rs file:

```
pub struct Meter
{
  someValue: f64
}

// some implementation here
```

Now when I want to use the Meter struct in main, I seem to need to write the following:

```
let someMeter = Units::Length::Meter::Meter::new(5.3);
```

What I would like is to write

```
let someMeter = Units::Length::Meter::new(5.3);
```

Though I'm not sure what exactly I should change in the mod.rs files to achieve this. I don't really want to change the folder structure as I like the way it is organized. Any insight into what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

I acknowledge that I'm not following rust naming conventions in this example.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, I think I figured it out.

First I had to change the naming convention as to not create conflicts between modules and structs (Meter module and Meter struct). Then I had to change my units/length/mod.rs file to:

```
mod meter;
pub use self::meter::Meter;
```